# Python: Be always running the program

Tags: python, gmail

I want this code never to break. So I have created a infinite loop and a "goto" to the beginning in case it breaks. However, It's still not working.

```
root@xxx:~# cat gmail2.py 
import imaplib, re
import os
import time
import socket
socket.setdefaulttimeout(60)

def again():
        conn = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com", 993)
        conn.login("xx@example.com", "xxx")

        while(True):
                unreadCount = re.search("UNSEEN (\d+)", conn.status("INBOX", "(UNSEEN)")[1][0]).group(1)
                print unreadCount

                if int(unreadCount) > 20:
                        os.system('heroku restart --app sss-xxxx-203')
                #os.system('ls')
                #print "Restarting server...."

                time.sleep(60)

again() 


1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gmail2.py", line 22, in <module>
    again()
  File "gmail2.py", line 12, in again
    unreadCount = re.search("UNSEEN (\d+)", conn.status("INBOX", "(UNSEEN)")[1][0]).group(1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/imaplib.py", line 703, in status
    typ, dat = self._simple_command(name, mailbox, names)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/imaplib.py", line 1060, in _simple_command
    return self._command_complete(name, self._command(name, *args))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/imaplib.py", line 890, in _command_complete
    raise self.abort('command: %s => %s' % (name, val))
imaplib.abort: command: STATUS => socket error: EOF
```

Comment: Your connection, inside your search call, isn't receiving any data or it hit the end of a file and that's why it's returning a socket error. Maybe add in a check for EOF before you call re.search(). Also, generally endless loops are dangerous, you might want to add in some kind of breaking condition.

Answer (score 5):

There isn't any "goto" here (or anywhere in Python), nor would this ensure that if the loop breaks it would keep running, for two reasons:

1. If an exception (such as `imaplib.abort` is thrown, the program will exit whatever functions it is in. Only a try/except would stop it from ending.
2. No matter how this program runs, `again()` will be called only once. Once the `again()` function has been called, it will complete and then continue after that point. It does *not* act as a goto- if the code breaks out of that while loop, it won't return to the `again` function.

What you really want is something like this:

```
import imaplib, re
import os
import time
import socket
socket.setdefaulttimeout(60)

while(True):
    conn = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com", 993)
    conn.login("xx@example.com", "xxx")

    try:
        unreadCount = re.search("UNSEEN (\d+)", conn.status("INBOX", "(UNSEEN)")[1][0]).group(1)
        print unreadCount

        if int(unreadCount) > 20:
            os.system('heroku restart --app sss-xxxx-203')
        #os.system('ls')
        #print "Restarting server...."

        time.sleep(60)
    except:
        # an error has been thrown- try again
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make sure that the code never stops running, you'll have to catch any exceptions that are thrown in `again`. Read up on [Python Exception handling.](http://docs.python.org/c-api/exceptions.html)

Since you are in an infinite loop (not a great idea, generally) you'll want to make sure that exceptions are handled intelligently, resolving the conditions that give rise to the exception in the first place. Otherwise, you'll just end up doing nothing repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

```
imap_host = 'imap.gmail.com'
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_host)
mail.login(user,passw)
mail.select("inbox") # connect to inbox.

while True:
    try:
        result, data = mail.uid('search', None, 'UNSEEN')
        uid_list = data[0].split()
        print len(uid_list), 'Unseen emails.'
        time.sleep(60)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print 'Quitting'
        return
```

You might want to try this.

Comment: Quick tip: use `break` instead of `return`.

Answer (score 0):

Try swapping `again()`

for this:

```
def main():
    while(True):        
        try:
            again()
        except:
            pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```